# Skip in Wordpress Post ID's, can this cause issues?

Tags: posts, woocommerce-offtopic

Hoping to get a quick answer to this, couldn't find any existing questions.

Long story short, someone on our system used a Woocommerce product importer plugin and set the Post ID's in the CSV to a random number. We now have a jump in our Post ID's of about 300,000, here's the relevant screenshot from PHPMyAdmin:

[image]

Question is, are there any issues that can be caused by this that I should be aware of it? And if so, what's the post approach to fixing the issue?

This is a production site so reverting back isn't really an option at this point, but if it's going to cause major issues I will. (The question of why someone was tossing random plugins straight into production is an issue for another day :p )

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the post ID is consistent (value is referenced correctly in post meta table and term relationship table or in any other relevant place) you'll have absolutely no issue.